js setTimeout function runs every 3s to receive messages , can convert it to Ajax Get ?
i have a messages chat on my video site .
it is not a comments , it is a chat runs in real time between users .
it is working like this :

a setTimeout function runs every 3 seconds all the time .
user1 send message .
setTimeout function is working so user2 get the message Immediately (3s).
setTimeout function working .
users send / not send the setTimeout function still working .
if stop this setTimeout function user2 will not see the message until refresh the page .

my hosting server company say this cause a heavy load on the cpu .
long polling , websocket , nodejs and other like these methods are not supported on my server .
so the only way i have to do , to convert this kind of code to Ajax .
but i dont have any knowledge of php/js coding .
NOTE: if it is possible to run the setTimeout function only if message sent , this will be great instead of change the code to ajax .
here all my code , php , html and js :
and if you need more codes i will post them
<?php 
if ($first == 'fetch') {
if (empty($_POST['last_id'])) {
$_POST['last_id'] = 0;
}
if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
$_POST['id'] = 0;
}
if (empty($_POST['first_id'])) {
$_POST['first_id'] = 0;
}
$messages_html = PT_GetMessages($_POST['id'], array('last_id' => $_POST['last_id'], 'first_id' => $_POST['first_id'], 'return_method' => 'html'));
if (!empty($messages_html)) {
$html = PT_LoadPage("messages/{$pt->config->server}/messages", array('MESSAGES' => $messages_html));
} else {
$html = PT_LoadPage("messages/ajax/no-messages");
}
$users_html = PT_GetMessagesUserList(array('return_method' => 'html'));
if (!empty($messages_html) || !empty($users_html)) {
$data = array('status' => 200, 'message' => $messages_html, 'users' => $users_html);
}
}
?>

<div class="user-send-message" >                        
<form action="#" method="POST" id="new-message-form" >
<textarea rows="1" name="new-message" id="new-message" ></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="send-button">send</button>
<input type="hidden" id="user-id" name="id" value="<?php echo $pt->chat_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="user-avatar" value="<?php echo ($pt->chat_user->avatar) ? $pt->chat_user->avatar : "";?>">
</form>                 
</div>

<script>
var messagesInterval = <?php echo (!empty($pt->extra_config->ajax_message_update_interval)) ? $pt->extra_config->ajax_message_update_interval : 3000 ?>;
$(function() {
window.UpdateChatU = setTimeout(function () {
fetchMessages();
}, messagesInterval);
});

function fetchMessages() {
clearTimeout(window.UpdateChatU);
$.post('{{LINK aj/messages/fetch}}', {id: $('#user-id').val(), last_id: $('.message:last').attr('data-id')}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
if (data.status == 200) {
if (data.message.length > 0) {
$('.messages').append(data.message);
$('.user-messages').scrollTop($('.user-messages')[0].scrollHeight);
}
if ($('#search-list').val() == 0) {
$('.messages-sidebar .list-group').html(data.users);
}
}
window.UpdateChatU = setTimeout(function () {
fetchMessages();
}, messagesInterval);
});
}
$(function() {
form.ajaxForm({
url: '{{LINK aj/messages/new}}?hash=' + $('.main_session').val(),
data: {message_id: $('#message_id').val()},
beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
if ($('.messages').length == 0) {
$('.user-messages').html('<div class="messages"></div>');
}
if ($('#new-message').val().length >= 1) {
$id = makeid();
formData.push({ name: 'message_id', value: $id });
$('.messages').append('<div class="data_message" data-id="' + $id + '"><div class="message to-user pull-right" data-id=""><div class="user-message">' + nl2br(escapeHTML($('#new-message').val())) + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
$('#new-message').val('');
$('#new-message').height(40); 
$('.user-messages').scrollTop($('.user-messages')[0].scrollHeight);
} else {
$('#new-message').val('');
} 
},
success: function(data,rew,rr) {
if (data.status == 400) {
$('.data_message[data-id="' + $id + '"]').remove();
swal({
title: '{{LANG error}}',
text: data.message,
type: 'error',
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
confirmButtonText: 'OK',
buttonsStyling: true,
confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
});
}
else{
$('.data_message[data-id="' + data.message_id + '"]').html(data.message);
}
}
});
});

</script>


This code is already using AJAX (what do you think $.post ajaxForm are doing??). There is no converting to be done. But yes, websockets would be a far better solution for a chat application like this. Consider moving to another server, or seeing if you can route this part of your solution through another service.

if it is possible to run the setTimeout function only if message sent...no, that's not possible. Think about it logically for a moment: the client-side code does not know if any messages have been sent by anyone else until it asks the server!

ok . i understand .
